# Select the most detailed level in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, hierarchical-data

I've been struggling to find a way to aggregate hierarchal data with my data set. My data already has the sums on every level. I need a way to display this data while allowing for drill throughs on the various levels. Additionally, not every path on my hierarchy goes out to the same level. My thought is to have a column that displays the most granular level in every path. I need a way to dynamically identify the "most detailed level in path" as seen in the picture below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You posted a similar question last week and I answered. That didn't work?

Comment: You can prepare a measure in which you will verify which level is currently displayed. You have the isinscope function for that https://dax.guide/isinscope/;
Combine it with IF or SWITCH

Comment: @mkRabbani that question was similar, but not the same. I think I am on the right path with this solution...

I have two columns, one with the current tier and then one with the immediate parent. I then do CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(table),ALL(table),table[Parent] = CurrentTier)) to get the number of children that a current tier has. If it doesn't have any children then I am assuming that it is the lowest level.

I do have an additional requirement that I have to build into that formula. I have some lower level tiers that are blank. I need to skip those ones